# Test fails when run in parallel in python selenium via pytest xdist but works well in sequence

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, pytest-xdist

When I run the below code with

`pytest  .\tests\GET\test_setupFunc.py`

it works perfectly
i.e. setup(my_fixture) function run once then test_one and test_two

if i run it **parallely** using **pytest-xdist** using this

`pytest  .\tests\GET\test_setupFunc.py -n=2`

it fails

i think my_fixture is being called by both test since i have setup the `scope="session"` that function should be shared.

**once that function is run successfully, I want parallelism should get trigger**

========== short test summary info =========

ERROR tests\GET\test_setupFunc.py::test_one - **selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
Could not remove old devtools port file.** Perhaps t...

please do replace **yourusername** with your username of system in addarguement code step in case you plan to run it

'''

```
import pytest
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def my_fixture():
   logging.warning('setup function')
   print(" i will be called only once i am one time")
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
   options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
   options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=c:\\Users\\yourUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
   driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
   driver.get("https://gmail.com")
   
   driver.quit()

def test_one():
    logging.warning('test_a')

    print(" i am first function")

def test_two():
    logging.warning('test_b')
    print(" i am second function")
```

Also to note if I remove `selenium` related steps and just keep print statements it works fine

**Expected Result**

1. setup method is called once
   2 methods should be called once setup ran successfully once

`pytest-parallel` does not support python 3.9 yet tried that as well